# How do a library function (C) call on gnu assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I compile a code.

```
.data
ssttrr:
.string "%d\n"
.text
.globl main
main:
mov $213, %rdx
push %rdx
push $ssttrr
call _printf
add  $8, %rsp
```

or it

```
.global main

    .text
main:

push    %rax                    # caller-save register
push    %rcx                    # caller-save register

mov     $format, %rdi           # set 1st parameter (format)
mov     %rax, %rsi              # set 2nd parameter (current_number)
xor     %rax, %rax              # because printf is varargs
call    printf                  # printf(format, current_number)

pop     %rcx                    # restore caller-save register
pop     %rax                    # restore caller-save register

mov     %rax, %rdx              # save the current number
mov     %rbx, %rax              # next number is now current
add     %rdx, %rbx              # get the new next number
dec     %ecx                    # count down
jnz     print                   # if not done counting, do some more

pop     %rbx                    # restore rbx before returning


mov  $60, %rax
xor  %rdi, %rdi
syscall

format:
    .asciz  "%20ld\n"
```

why the "format" is in a .text field?

```
gcc -nostdlib file.s -o program
```

Why do I get an error?

> /universe/earth/asm/file.s:14: undefined reference to `_printf'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

how to fix this error?

if so then all the code works. Why???

```
.global main

    .text
main:
    push    %rbx                    # we have to save this since we use it

    mov     $90, %ecx               # ecx will countdown to 0
    xor     %rax, %rax              # rax will hold the current number
    xor     %rbx, %rbx              # rbx will hold the next number
    inc     %rbx                    # rbx is originally 1
print:
    # We need to call printf, but we are using eax, ebx, and ecx.  printf
    # may destroy eax and ecx so we will save these before the call and
    # restore them afterwards.

    push    %rax                    # caller-save register
    push    %rcx                    # caller-save register

    mov     $format, %rdi           # set 1st parameter (format)
    mov     %rax, %rsi              # set 2nd parameter (current_number)
    xor     %rax, %rax              # because printf is varargs
    call    printf                  # printf(format, current_number)

    pop     %rcx                    # restore caller-save register
    pop     %rax                    # restore caller-save register

    mov     %rax, %rdx              # save the current number
    mov     %rbx, %rax              # next number is now current
    add     %rdx, %rbx              # get the new next number
    dec     %ecx                    # count down
    jnz     print                   # if not done counting, do some more

    pop     %rbx                    # restore rbx before returning
    ret
 format:
    .asciz  "%20ld\n"
```

Why the function print: isn't called in main field?

cpy: intel-64
os: debian

Comment: Huh? If you want to call `printf()`, a function in the C standard library, then why are you telling the compiler *not* to link to that library?

Comment: It is very strange phenomenon but so wrote in manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the "format" is in a .text field?

.text in assembly means "code section"

> gcc -nostdlib file.s -o program
>   Why do I get an error?
>   /universe/earth/asm/file.s:14: undefined reference to `_printf' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

you are not linking the standard libraries, where printf is located (-nostdlib option): the linker cannot find it

> how to fix this error?

Either link the standard library (stdlib) explicitly, or link another library that provides a printf implementation, or remove the -nostdlib switch

> Why the function print: isn't called in main field?

"print" is just a label: you can call it, jmp to it, or just let the control flow of the program go into it, as in this case.
(I can tell that print is not a "function" because it lacks a proper prologue).

May I suggest you some assembly introductions?

- http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro.html
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Introduction
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Assembly-HOWTO/

Or many others you can find on the internet

Comment: how do I link the C standard library? **gcc -g3 hello3.s -o hello** and I get  hello3.s:14: undefined reference to `_printf'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

*why the "format" is in a .text field?*
It's unclear what you're asking here, but I think you're asking about two things, compressed here:

```
mov     $format, %rdi           # set 1st parameter (format)

format:
    .asciz  "%20ld\n"
```

In your `.text` section, you're refering to the `format` label. Later, you define the `format` label.

*Why do I get an error?*
You're specifying the compiler option `-nostdlib` which excludes the libraries that normally get included, including the `printf` function.

*Why the function print: isn't called in main field?*
There isn't a *function* print, but there is a label, and it *is* being used:

```
jnz     print                   # if not done counting, do some more
```

It appears to be the termination point of a loop based on `%ecx`, which counts from 0x90 to 0.